# Why am I getting duplicate abstract subclass array data?

Tags: java, arrays, object, duplicates, abstract

I'm trying to store subclass objects of an abstract class in an array.

I'm not receiving error messages, but when calling to print array information, I see only 5 duplicates of the last user-input account. When inputting the data, however, the output is unique per entry upon prompting for input. I think something is going wrong inside my if/else statement nested in the for-loop (as shown below).

My code will be a little abridged to conserve space.

Edit1: This is my first question so if I can improve it please let me know!

```
// BankAccountTest

public class BankAccountTest {
  int numAccHolders = in.nextInt();
  BankAccount[] bankaccounts = new BankAccount[numAccHolders];
  BankAccount.generateAccountDetails(bankaccounts, numAccHolders);

// BankAccount

public abstract class BankAccount {
  protected static double balance;
  protected static int accNum;
  protected static int accType;

  public BankAccount(double balance, int accNum, int accType){
    this.balance = balance; 
    this.accNum = accNum; 
    this.accType = accType;
  }

  public getBalance(){
    return balance;
  }
  public getAccNumber(){
    return accNumber;
  }

  public static void generateAccountDetails(BankAccount[] bankaccounts, 
    int numAccHolders){
    for(int i = 0; i < numAccHolders; i++){
      accNum = (i + 1);
      int accType = in.nextInt();
      double balance = in.nextDouble();

      if(accType == 1){ 
        bankaccounts[i] = new ChequingsAccount(balance, accNum, accType);
      } else if (accType == 2) {
        bankaccounts[i] = new SavingsAccount(balance, accNum, accType);
      }

// ChequingsAccount

public class ChequingsAccount extends BankAccount {
  public ChequingsAccount(double balance, int accNum, int accType)
  super(balance, accNum, accType);

// SavingsAccount

public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {
public SavingsAccount(double balance, int accNum, int accType)
super(balance, accNum, accType);
```

Comment: Please indent, code is so unreadable

Comment: Code is also incomplete

Answer (score 0):

The attributes `BankAccount.balance`, `BankAccount.accNum`, `BankAccount.accType` should not be static. They are shared between ALL the instances.